# How does the Facebook Like button work?

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, widget

I want to provide a simple piece of Javascript (or an iframe, I guess) that allows 3rd parties to embed functionality from my site in theirs. The user of said widget will be authenticated on our site already - so basically the Facebook Like button, or Facebook Connect, are the closest examples I could find.

Since Facebook has a few different buttons I'm struggling to understand exactly what they're doing though. Is there a succinct (and technical - I'm a developer and want to build my own widget) explanation somewhere? I'm particularly focused on the security issues involved.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[Here](http://dorianroy.com/blog/2010/04/how-facebooks-like-button-works/) is a brief explanation of the facebook 'like' button and [here](http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/) is a tutorial on how to build a web widget. Finally [here](http://jeremiahgrossman.blogspot.com/2010/07/third-party-web-widget-security-faq.html) is a discussion on the security of web widgets.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Like button is using cookies to obtain your FB user information, that with additional attributes are then sent to a service endpoint.

As for security measures, an obvious would be to allow requests only from websites with given access keys.