# How does Facebook update likes withot refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, web

The title says it all.
When you click like on Facebook, it shows liked and increments the like counter without refreshing the whole page.
How it works?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the Facebook Like button work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256083/how-does-the-facebook-like-button-work)

Comment: @HarshGundecha The answer explains about who widget of Facebook like button work on external site. I want to know how the like counter is incremented dynamically without refreshing the whole page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly it uses javascript or some framework of javascript. See [example](https://jsfiddle.net/k7okshpv/2/). Example gets the current count and if you click the like button it increments by one.

```
$(".like").click(function () {
    var counter = $(".likecounter").text();
    counter = parseInt(counter);
  counter = counter+1;
    $(".likecounter").html(counter);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Facebook uses a Javascript framework/library/whatever you want to call it called [React](https://reactjs.org/), in fact Facebook are the creators / maintainers of React.

What happens is when you click the like button, a javascript variable in the facebook application state gets updated by adding 1 to it. The element is then updated with this new value. It's fairly straight forward stuff, in fact [There's even a demo for something similar](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/counter) on the React Redux github page.