# How to create a javascript badge with css

Tags: javascript

Hi there I was looking into creating an award badge that my cliens can embedd into their sites so I can get a backlink. Obviously I want control of the anchor text so I decided it is easier and nicer to create a javascript widget. I followed these instructions here [similar questions answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248351/how-can-i-create-a-javascript-badge-or-widget#)
but I want to add css and text to my badge so am wondering how to do that within the code. Any help is appreciated thanks.
Here is the code

```js
var scriptTag, badge;
scriptTag = document.getElementById('badge');
badge = document.createElement('DIV');
badge.innerHTML = '<p>Wow, cool!</p>';
scriptTag.parentNode.replaceChild(badge, scriptTag);
```

I was looking to create something like tripadvisor but without too much code
[tripadvisor badge](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Widgets-g60750-d665258-Hard_Rock_Hotel_San_Diego-San_Diego_California.html#w-certificateOfExcellence)

Comment: HTML elements have "style" - is that what you mean by adding css, or did you want to add a CSS stylesheet?

Comment: Theoretically, if your clients load a JS file from your server, and can place a div with an id unique to you, you should be able to inject everything else you need into the page

Comment: I wanted to add css style sheet, how can I call the css with the javscript?